# Can left join be optimized in 'preferred users' MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, left-join, database-optimization

I have two tables:

**poll_response** (poll_id, option_id, user_id)
*(about 500,000 rows, with 500 unique polls, 1000 unique options, and 25000 unique users)*

**preferred_users** (user_id)
*(about 800 rows)*

I'd like to determine what percentage of the users who select each option are "preferred users" (i.e. those with high reputation).  Other users can respond to the poll; in order to identify that the response came from a preferred user, the join is required to the preferred_users table.

Here's what I've got:

```
SELECT option_id, count(*) AS all_votes, count(preferred_users.user_id) AS preferred_votes
FROM response
LEFT JOIN preferred_users ON response.user_id = preferred_users.user_id
GROUP BY option_id
```

The query spits out a table like this:

```
| option_id | all_votes | preferred_votes
| 1         | 500       | 150
| 2         | 550       | 250
| 3         | 525       | 300
```

I can then do the math to determine the percentage.

The problem is that the query often times out -- meaning it takes well over a minute to complete.

Is there any way to get rid of the left join or otherwise optimize the query?

Comment: What indexes do you have on these tables?

Comment: BTREE index for each column in poll_response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried splitting it into two queries - one for the total and one for the preferred users?  i suspect that what is causing it to run slowly is running through the entries in group counting the non-null entries (but you could see yourself by using explain).

in other words:

```
select option_id, count(*) from response group by option_id
select option_id, count(*) from response, preferred_users where response.user_id = preferred_user.id group by option_id
```

you could even join them:

```
select * from 
  (select option_id, count(*) as total from response group by option_id
   left join
   select option_id, count(*) as preferred from response, preferred_users where response.user_id = preferred_user.id group by option_id
   using (option_id))
```

(not sure if i have the syntax right there, but you get the idea).

also, you have an index on the preferred_users.id column too, right?  and a foreign key relation from one to the other?  if not, try with that first.